# SwiftUI Textfield Rounding Up Input Issue

Tags: swiftui, rounding, textfield

I'm having a textfield rounding issue. If I input anywhere from 1 to 1.49 all is good. If I input 1.5 or up (to 1.999) the field rounds up to 2. How do I keep this as what I input. If I input 1.73 I want it to remain 1.73, not 2. Here's the code:

```
                        VStack {
                            let lineOneProxy = Binding<String>(
                                get: { if self.lineOne == 0 {
                                    return ""
                                } else {
                                    return String(format: "%.0f", Double(self.lineOne)) }
                                },
                                set: { if let value = NumberFormatter().number(from: $0) {
                                    self.lineOne = value.doubleValue }
                                }
                            )
                            TextField("ENTER", text: lineOneProxy.max(5))
                        }
```

This is how I have NumberFormatter set up:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: Style, locale: Locale = .current) {
        self.init()
        self.locale = locale
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that is what you told it to do. In this line:

```
return String(format: "%.0f", Double(self.lineOne)) }
```

specifying `%.0f` means to round up at half with no(0) fractional digits.

Given a double `value = 1234.12345`,

```
String(format: "%.0f", value)  // 1234
String(format: "%.1f", value)  // 1234.1
String(format: "%.2f", value)  // 1234.12
String(format: "%.3f", value)  // 1234.123
String(format: "%.4f", value)  // 1234.1235 - The 4 rounded up due to the trailing 5
```

Edit:

You asked why you were getting the value that you were. The answer is obvious, if you don't want the behavior,do not use the `%.0f" formatter. You never said what outcome you specifically wanted, but I am guessing 2 fractional digits from the way you worded some things. If you want 2 fractional digits, use the formatter you created and edit it to this:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: Style, locale: Locale = .current) {
        self.init()
        self.locale = locale
        // Set the fractional digits here:
        self.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
struct DoubleStringFormat: View {

    @State var value = 1234.12345

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Enter Value: ")
                TextField("", value: $value, format: .number)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            Text(String(format: "%.0f", value))
            Text(String(format: "%.1f", value))
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", value))
            Text(String(format: "%.3f", value))
            Text(String(format: "%.4f", value))
            // Use your NumberFormatter here:
            Text(NumberFormatter(numberStyle: .decimal).string(from: value as NSNumber) ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work as it adds the decimal places for you, meaning if you input 1 you instantly get 1.0 for "%.1f" or 1.00 for "%.2f" etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if I can get this to work. I'm still pretty new to all of this.